# What is needed to force polynomial-ring automorphisms to be affine?

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Is there an [integral domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) $R$ and a polynomial-ring automorphism $\: \phi : R[x] \to R[x] \:$ such that, for $\: i : R\to R[x] \:$ the canonical embedding, $\;\;\; \phi \circ i \: = \: i \;\;$ and

there do **not** exist elements $c$ and $u$ of $R$ such that $u$ is a unit and $\;\; \phi(x) \: = \: c+(u\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}x) \;\;\;$?

[

More generally, what properties of rings $R$ suffice to rule out the existence of such a $\phi$?

Clearly, $R$ must have a $1$, since otherwise the identity function would be such a $\phi$.

If $R$ has a $1$ and an $\epsilon$ such that $\: \epsilon^{\hspace{.02 in}2} \hspace{-0.0 in} = 0 \neq \epsilon \:$ and $\: \epsilon \in \:$[Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28algebra%29)$(R)\:$, $\:$ then the homomorphism given by,

for $\: c\in R \:$, $\:$ $\: i(c) \mapsto i(c) \:$ and $\;\; x \: \mapsto \: x+(\epsilon \hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}x^{\hspace{.02 in}2}) \;\;$, $\;\;\;$ is such a $\phi$.

]

Comment: I don't think you normally say "square-root of zero" as much as saying that $\epsilon$ is nilpotent.

Comment: At least for the example I gave, I really need $\: \epsilon^2 = 0 \:$, $\:$ not just that $\epsilon$ is nilpotent. $\hspace{1.66 in}$

Comment: Sure, so you would likely say something to that effect. Anyway, you said $R$ is an integral domain, so there are no such elements.

Answer (score 4):

In light of our conversation, let me change my answer as follows:

Let us assume that $R$ is commutative. If $R$ is not commutative other nastiness will follow.

If $R$ is commutative, the property that $R$ is fixed by the automorphism is equivalent to $\phi: R[x] \to R[x]$ being an $R$-algebra automorphism. This means that generators must map to generators under $\phi$. Fixing a generator $\langle x \rangle = R[x]$ for the domain, means that it is sufficient to find the collection of all generators for $R[x]$, define a set-theoretic map $x \mapsto g$ for some generator $g$, then extend "linearly/multiplicatively."

Thus the question is reduced to, "Under what conditions on $R$ allows for more than just  'affine' generators $p(x) = a+bx$ of $R[x]$?" Now, I think it is reasonable to say that if $R$ is an integral domain (so it has no zero divisors), that this is not possible. The reason being that if $R$ is an integral domain, the polynomial degree map does what we think it should, i.e. $\deg p(x)q(x) = \deg p(x) + \deg q(x)$, so if $g(x)$ is a generator of degree at least $2$, we will not be able to generate $R[x]$. This technically resolves your question for **integral domains.**

The more interesting question is, what if we do not limit ourselves to integral domains? Your example demonstrates that such an automorphism is possible if the ring admits nilpotent elements. In fact, your example should generalize to more than just square-nilpotent elements. Namely, if there exists $\epsilon \in R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\epsilon^p = 0$ then the map on generators sending $x \mapsto x + \epsilon^{p-1} x^p$ will be such an automorphism, since we can generate $x$ via $\phi(x-\epsilon^{p-1} x^p)$ and all other powers of $x^n$ are derivative of that. We can generalize further, by saying that if $R$ admits a family of nilpotents $\epsilon_i$ such that $\epsilon_i^{p_i}=0$ then $x \mapsto x + \sum_{i\in I}\epsilon_i^{p_i-1} x^{p_i}$ should be a generator for any *finite* index set $I$.

Thus I suppose the answer to your question is: If $R$ is commutative, such automorphism exist so long as the nilradical $\mathfrak n \subset R$ is non-trivial.

In the non-commutative case, you can no longer say that $\phi$ is an $R$-algebra automorphism, so it is not clear to me that we can make such an assertion on generators.

Comment: Injectivity only gives $\;\; \epsilon \hspace{-0.03 in} \cdot \hspace{-0.03 in} x \: = \: \epsilon \hspace{-0.03 in} \cdot \hspace{-0.03 in} y \;\;$, $\;\;$ not necessarily $\: x = y \;$. $\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Touche! Though I do not think it changes the validity of the proof at the bottom.

Comment: You have just deduced that $\;\; a \: = \: (-\epsilon) \cdot x^2 \;\;\;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Yep, so I took that whole thing out. Nicely, I was trying to figure out what $\phi^{-1}(x)$ was and I found it. In any case, can you find a flaw in the latter argument?

Comment: The additivity requirement should also be enough to guarantee that $a=0$.

Comment: I just realized that in order for the map to be multiplicative, $\epsilon$ needs to be in the center of $R$. $\:$ When that is the case, the universal property of polynomial rings will force the map to be additive, despite the $x^2$ component. $\;\;\;$ (Similarly, additivity of the map won't guarantee $\: a=0 \;$.) $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Since there is a ring with such a $\phi$, though not an integral domain, you need to assume something else if you say "regardless of whether or not it is an integral domain." $\;\;\;$ In general, one can say that $\: 0 < \operatorname{degree}(\phi(x)) \:$ and if $\phi(x)$ is not of the indicated affine form then its leading coefficient is a zero divisor. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: When $R$ is an integral domain, the center of $R$ is all of $R$ (integral domains are commutative). Also, what you need is not that $\epsilon$ is in the center of $R$, but that $R$ has characteristic $2$. For example,
$\phi(2x) = \phi(x)+\phi(x)$ but $\phi(2x) = 2x + 4\epsilon x^2$ while $2\phi(x) = 2x + 2\epsilon x^2$. In general, you would need $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ which which only happens in commutative rings with char 2.

Comment: Also, unless I am mistaken, the universal property of polynomial rings is that every *ring homomorphism* factors through the polynomial ring, essentially through the evaluation map. Why would this force additivity at all?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing now! I don't think that you are using the universal property of polynomial rings, so much as the "algebra morphism extension" property on free algebras; that is, let $R[x]$ be the free-algebra on a single generator. By specifying where that generator is mapped to, you can use the universal property of *free algebras* to extend this map uniquely to an algebra map which sends the generator $x$ to the element $x + \epsilon x^2$.

Comment: But if that is what you mean, I cannot see how the map is an isomorphism. In particular, how do you generate just the element $x^n$? Notice that $(x+\epsilon x^2)^n = x^n + \epsilon \begin{pmatrix} n \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} x^{n+1}$. Thus for any $a$ which is not $0$ or $\epsilon$, $\phi(ax^n) = a\phi(x) = ax^n + a\epsilon x^{n+1}$ has degree $n+1$. So how do you get degree 1? You either need $n=0$ (impossible since constants are fixed) or $a = \epsilon$, which gives $\phi(\epsilon x) = \epsilon x$. As $\epsilon$ is a zero divisor, you cannot isolate $x$, and this is the only way to get deg 1.

Comment: Where do you get $\;\; \phi(2\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}x) \: = \: (2\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}x)+(4\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}\epsilon \hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}x^2) \;\;$ from? $\;\;\;\;\;\;$ I generate the element $x^{\hspace{.02 in}n}$ as $\;\; \phi\hspace{-0.02 in}\left(\hspace{-0.03 in}\left(x+\hspace{-0.03 in}\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}(-\epsilon) \hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}x^{\hspace{.02 in}2}\hspace{-0.03 in}\right)\hspace{-0.03 in}\right)^n\hspace{-0.02 in}\right) \:\:\:$. $\hspace{.64 in}$